# Highlight the field in colour when data is inserted

Tags: apex, visualforce, lightning-aura-components, community, salesforcedx

I am just new in salesforce, I have a one custom field name as "Test__c" this is a text field, I want to highlight this field with blue color when the data is inserted and stored in the Salesforce org. We are creating the case though the community page.

Can anyone have an idea about this concern how can we do this in salesforce org ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible on the standard Salesforce record detail page. However, if you are using custom lightning/visualforce page then you can achieve through custom styling/CSS.

Comment: Thanks for your revert . Can you please share the styling css to implement this